# How to check if there is space available in a linear layout

Tags: android, view, android-linearlayout

I have linearlayout that with horizontal orientation.

I am adding ImageView item in it with inflating ImageViews. 
How can I check if there is no more space in the linear layout ?

For example in small screens I will add only 5 items but on big screens I will add up to 8. (depending of the size of the screen)

Comment: (loopcount + 1) * imageWidth > linearLayoutHeght then break the loop. If you are starting the loop from 0 :)

Comment: Can you give me some snippet of link of how you measured the size ? , cause getWidth() returns 0

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827079/measuring-a-view-before-rendering-it see this link

Answer (score 2):

You can maybe take a look at this example.

http://hzqtc.github.io/2013/12/android-custom-layout-flowlayout.html

Comment: Perfect answer for multiline views