# Android M footerView.getMeasuredHeight() returns incorrectly

Tags: android, android-view, android-6.0-marshmallow

On Android M

```
footerView.getMeasuredHeight()
```

returns 3373. This happens on all the devices I've checked which run Android M. On a Nexus 5 it does not happen on KitKat version but does on the M version. I run on actual devices and never on an emulator.

The measuring occurs after the following code:

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View appListItemView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.view_selectable_app, null);
View headerView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.app_feeds_container_header, null);
View footerView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.apps_feed_container_footer, null);

appListItemView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
headerView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
footerView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

appListItemView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
headerView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
footerView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
```

It is important to not that header is measured correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using wrong parameters for the `measure()` call.
Here's an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8403680/1395437

The footerView measure is surely incorrect, because you ask for `EXACTLY`, but exactly how much?

Instead, it should be something like:

```
int widthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(parent.getWidth(), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
int heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
footerView.measure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
```