# getHeight() doesn't get the height of the layout

Tags: android, android-view, appcompatdialogfragment

I'm going to use dialog fragments.

There is an item called `writing_comment_item.xml` in the `dialogfragment`, and I want to set the `height` of `5` items.

I used the inflate() function, I used `getHeight()` to get the layout.

But as a result of debugging, the height is `0` no matter how much.

I tried in `onCreate()`. Also tried `onCreateView()` as well.

But the result was the same

What should I do?

***writing_comment_item.xml***

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".fragment.WritingCommentDialogFragment">
   
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/comment_edit"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_bullet_point"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:maxLength="22"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
    </EditText>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

***WCDialogFragment.java***

```
public class WritingCommentDialogFragment extends DialogFragment implements CommentModel.EditInputListener {
    OnBackPressedCallback callback;

    LinearLayout commentContainer; // input layout
    private final List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<>();
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_writing_comment_dialog, container, false);

        bindViews(view);
        addCommentItem();
        return view;
    }

    private void bindViews(View v) {
        commentContainer = v.findViewById(R.id.container);
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        return dialog;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setDialogSize();
    }

    private void setDialogSize() {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.writing_comment_item, null, false);
        int h = v.getHeight() * 5;

        getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(1000, h);
    }
}
```

---

***EDITED***

```
private void setDialogSize() {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.writing_comment_item, null, false);
        v.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        v.getMeasuredHeight();
        int h = v.getMeasuredHeight() * 5;
        getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(1000, h);
    }
```

***ADDED PIC***
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3594216/4303296 ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [View's getWidth() and getHeight() returns 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591784/views-getwidth-and-getheight-returns-0)

Comment: @Beko I also saw the answer from the link. But I can't get the height for only one item...
I've added the code

Comment: @Henry Twist I also saw the answer from the link. But I can't get the height for only one item... I've added the code

Comment: I've had problems with this before as well. Unfortunately I think there's nothing more to be said than what's already been told in the above links. I think you'll have to read through those answers and comments and try to figure out which one will work for you. Wish you good luck.

Comment: Looking at your updated code you seem to be inflating a layout but not using it? But trying to use its height?

Comment: @Henry Twist Yes, I simply want to set the height of the dialog fragment by 5 heights of the corresponding layout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mistake here is trying to get the height of a view that hasn't been added to the layout hierarchy. When you call

```
inflate(R.layout.writing_comment_item, null, false);
```

with `attachToRoot` being `false`, you are specifying that you don't want it to be added to the hierarchy yet so the system never measures the view.

You could instead call `View.measure(int, int)` yourself and then use `View.getMeasuredHeight()`. This question covers that in a bit more detail - [Measuring a view before rendering it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8403680/10082297)

Comment: Wow thanks, it's almost solved. Almost means because there is a problem a little. i wanted to set the height of the item as many as 5, so I multiplied the value obtained with `getMeasuredHeight()` by `5`. However, the result is not all 5 items, but a bit cut off. In other words, the size of the dialog is slightly smaller. Do you know why? and i editted code

Comment: Your code doesn't actually seem to be using the measured height?

Comment: It seems to be using height to be precise.

However, it is not the height of five.

The item comes out a bit cut off. i post picture