# How to calculate how many items fit(visible) in screen at recyclerview?

Tags: android, list, android-recyclerview, android-listview, android-adapter

I have a simple recycler view and their adapter
my question is that how to calculate how many items fit(visible) in screen at recycler view?
for example if my data list size is 30 and visible item in screen is 10
how can calculate number 10 (before loaded items in the list)?

Answer (score 1):

if you have `RecyclerView` then you have set [`LayoutManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager), probably [`LinearLayoutManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/LinearLayoutManager), which have methods like [`findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/LinearLayoutManager#findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()) or partially visible, and similar for last also. you can calculate how much items are (completly or at least partially) visible on screen

edit: just read that you want these numbers BEFORE any drawing... thats a game changer, you probably should measure screen or layout and item size by self. making it easier: maybe it may be fixed height? or make a "dirty hack", populate `RecyclerView` with dummy data and draw `INVISIBLE` items just for measuring, then measure like above, and finally set "real" data for `RecyclerView`

Comment: thanks for your help , height of recycler  view is match_parent and layoutManger as you said is LinearLayoutManager 
@snachmsm

Comment: excuse me can you show me an example that how to measure adapter item view? @snachmsm

Comment: it's not easy task, check out [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827079/measuring-a-view-before-rendering-it)